# What dose (.*) mean in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was reading a learning python book, and this was in one of the examples so I was wonder if this meant something.

Comment: Please show a more complete example. It's probably part of a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really weird way of explaining it but:    .* when used in files means a group of files... like if you used 
`fruits.*` instead of `fruits.apple`, it would be like saying `fruits.apples`, `fruits.oranges`, `fruits.bananas`, and any other files in the fruits group.

Comment: This is _one thing_ that `.*` can mean, in certain contexts, but not the only thing.

Comment: And, as you previously stated, the question-asker did not provide either of us with very much information to work with.

Comment: Yes, but without a note that this was only one possibility, your answer could be misleading.

Comment: But my answer could also be correct

Comment: I didn't downvote, I added a comment. It was aimed at future readers / the OP, not you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry I did't give you guys much info to work with.

Comment: You asked, I answered. Its all good :)

Answer (score 1):

(.*) doesn't mean anything specific in Python. However, it can mean specific things to certain functions when a part of a string. Hence `'(.*)'` might mean something to a function, although it means nothing to Python itself. Since

Two functions that do take strings containing (.*) are [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html), [fnmatch.fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) and the re modules functions.

In glob and fnmatch it is `'*'` that has special meaning, it means "anything". You typically use it to match filenames:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('/tmp/foobar.*')
['/tmp/foobar.tmp', '/tmp/foobar.txt', '/tmp/foobar.conf']
```

And you can also list everything with a specific ending:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('/tmp/*.txt')
['/tmp/foobar.txt', '/tmp/frotz.txt', '/tmp/wfsh.txt']
```

Hence, in these modules `'(.*)'` would mean anything starts with (. and ends with ) with anything in between it.

In the re module you handle regular expressions. regular expressions is a highly magical text matching language. There `'.'` means "any character (except newlines, unless you set a special flag to make it mean newlines as well)", and '*' means "zero to infinite amount of repetitions of the previous match". Hence `'.*'` means "pretty much anything", and is a common thing to stick into regular expressions, as `'foobar.*'` would mean anything that start with foobar.

Parenthesis means "groups", and to know what that mean you'll just have to read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). You probably won't get it without some experimentation so you see what happens.

Basically '(.*)' matches anything. I'm assuming your regular expression has text before and after it as well?